# conda refuses to install no matter python version

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I've created a package with no particular requirements for Python version, when I create conda environment with Python 3.8, it tells me that it will only install if I change my Python version to anything else, but Python 3.8, when I try it with 3.9, for example, then it tells me that that my package can only be installed if my Python version is 3.8.

Needless to say that `--no-deps` does nothing in this context. When I look up the metadata from the package.tar.bz2, I can see that `conda` added a bunch of requirements that were never there (in particular, it added Python version).

Below is a truly idiotic error message I was able to solicit from `conda`, which, essentially, claims that everything is honky-dory, but it fails anyways:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 404) for https://conda.anaconda.org/<snip>/linux-64/current_repodata.json

done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 261, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 281, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._run_sat(ssc)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 815, in _run_sat
    ssc.solution_precs = ssc.r.solve(tuple(final_environment_specs),
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 1320, in solve
    raise UnsatisfiableError({})
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: 
Did not find conflicting dependencies. If you would like to know which
packages conflict ensure that you have enabled unsatisfiable hints.

conda config --set unsatisfiable_hints True
            

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 20, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 308, in install
    raise e
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 295, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 275, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._add_specs(ssc)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 704, in _add_specs
    ssc.r.find_conflicts(spec_set)
  File "/home/wvxvw/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 352, in find_conflicts
    raise UnsatisfiableError(bad_deps, strict=strict_channel_priority)
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - <snip> -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

By the way, I did enable reporting of unsatisfiable dependencies, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: What happens if you try to install the package alone in its own environment? E.g., `conda create -n foo package.tar.bz2`  What Python version does it end up installing? Also, maybe you should be sharing your `conda build` commands, since that seems like more of the issue. Last, do you have any idea why it can't retrieve repodata? Are you offline?

Comment: I sort of figured out what the problem is. Or, rather problems. It's `conda` misreporting the problem. What actually happens is that some dependencies this package has come from `conda-forge`, but the main channels also has the libraries, albeit older versions. So, instead of telling me that it cannot find recent enough libraries, it tells me my version of Python is wrong.

Comment: On top of it, `conda-build` generates defective packages, unless you change somehow what gets stored as the required Python version (how one does it is still a mystery to me). And the cherry on top: the solver works incorrectly suggesting that there is a way to install a package if only you use different version of Python (where it should've given up and said that that's not possible).

Comment: Yeah, the solver seems to be particularly confounded by channel conflicts. I see you filed a bug report (thanks!). Python versions are usually controlled via build variants (see [the first example in the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html#build-variants)).